# Clearing select2 working from console but not from program?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I actually want my select2 fields to get their value cleared when that page loads whether its a refresh or from the back button of the browser.

So I put this on javascript so it runs

```
$('#warehouse-categories').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Though it is not giving any error but its actually affecting not at all. But when I enter the same command in developer console, then this commands seems to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#warehouse-categories').val(null).trigger('change');
```

this should work fine, or maybe there is something wrong on the placement of your script.

> The `<script>` tag can be placed in the `<head>` section of your HTML, in the `<body>` section, or after the `</body>` close tag, depending on when you want the JavaScript to load. - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html

you can also try this one

```
$('#warehouse-categories').val("").trigger('change');
```

Comment: I have added everything correct regarding script. Everything else is working. I put them inside a function logging to console to check. Its logging. But I have no idea why its not working through my program.